# Need to set a console app on windows startup from WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, console, filesystemwatcher

I have a WPF app that allows a user to setup several backups of source and destination directories of their choosing.  All this app does is take the user data and save it into a SQLite database.  I need the WPF then to set a registry key for a console app (or maybe something else that I am not aware of) to run in the background and start on Windows Start Up.  The background app queries the SQLite database and then creates File System Watchers to handle changes to the source and destination directories.  I know how to set the registry to run on  windows start; however, I do not know how to reference the background app from the WPF.

I have created a WPF app and a console app in the same solution; however, I do not know how to publish both so when a user installs the app, the WPF front in has access to the background app to set on windows startup.

Comment: Ok I figured this out.  I had to add a reference of the background application in the WPF app.  From there I could give the path of the background exe to the registry.  I feel like an idiot.   I have a fairly good grasp of code; however, deploying applications is a bit new to me.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Now I am having trouble accessing the Sqlite in the wpf app from the background app.  I thought if the WPF app referenced the background app, I would have access.  Any ideas?  If I execute the background app from the bin\debug folder it can access the sqlite file.  Anywhere else, it cannot.